# Add link to Buddypress profile tab secondary menu

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Hi I would like to add a link through the WordPress menus to goto a Buddypress Profile tab and to its secondary menu for the logged in user.

Example link would be like site/members/{usernamehere}/my-profile-menu/test/

[image]

Following another guide online I was able to add the my-profile-menu part but would like to add its child links to the tabs into the main wordpress menu.

https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/buddypress-links-in-wordpress-menus/#add-menu-links-specific-to-the-logged-in-member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dynamic BuddyPress profile links for the logged-in user by using 'me' as the user name.

Example: `.../members/me/my-profile-menu/test/`